# Couchbase running in a container not accessible

Tags: centos, docker, couchbase

So I've created this Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos

EXPOSE 7081 8092 11210 

RUN yum install -y \
    hostname \
    initscripts \
    openssl098e \
    pkgconfig \
    sudo \
    tar \
    wget \
    && wget http://packages.couchbase.com/releases/3.0.2/couchbase-server-enterprise-3.0.2-centos6.x86_64.rpm \
    && yum install -y couchbase-server-enterprise-3.0.2-centos6.x86_64.rpm \
    && rm -f ./couchbase-server-enterprise-3.0.2-centos6.x86_64.rpm \

CMD /opt/couchbase/bin/couchbase-server start -- -noinput
```

And that seems to be working (running the couchbase server) and to build and run it I do:

```
docker build -t="my/couchbase" .
docker run -itd --name=couchbase -p 11210:11210 -p 8091:7081 -p 8092:8092 my/couchbase
```

Now for some reason I can't connect to it via http. I tried to get ip address of the container with `docker inspect couchbase | grep IP`
and then going to `http://containters_ip:7081`

It's trying to get there for a very long time, but eventually times out.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `-p 8091:7081` is that a typo? Shouldn't they both be `7081`?

Comment: @PeterLyons No, the Couchbase Server web console listens on 8091.

Comment: @Agzam Have you see this [blog](http://tleyden.github.io/blog/2014/11/01/running-couchbase-cluster-under-coreos-on-aws/) about couchbase and docker, they might help.

Comment: @Paddy the blog explains how to run older version of Couchbase. Not very helpful for me

Comment: @Agzam There has not been many changes between 3.0.1 and 3.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

You need `EXPOSE 8091 8092 11210` (think of this as "the container listens on these ports") and `-p 7081:8091` to get the mapping you seek. In `-p` it's `hostport:containerport` order.

Comment: did exactly as you said - still nothing

Comment: I think the fact that I'm starting the couchbase server is not enough. Maybe I need to kick off the cluster somehow (?)

Comment: Well you can use `docker exec -i -t couchbase bash` then run `netstat -ntlp` inside the container to verify which TCP ports are actually listening. If nothing is listening on 8091 then that's the problem. But I don't know couchbase so I can only help on the docker end of this question.